# Anyone find value migrating to NightWatch from Python Selenium API?

Tags: selenium, selenium2, selenium-webdriver, python, javascript

My dilemma, I have tons of tests and experience on the Python API to Selenium and webdriver. But, my dev team is big time javascript fans who think everything should be built under node/js. I want to build out some NightWatch E2E tests to satisfy them, but that sparked a debate that we should migrate everything over to javascript testing.

Any thoughts, ideas on dealing with this conversation? Personally, I think Python is easy to integrate into other QA software as well and even through testing it feels cleaner and more reliable. I have nothing against javascript but it just does not make sense in my eyes to use it for QA just because of the stack the team is using.

Comment: I agree with you with the preference for Python (and I DO have something against quirks of JS, of which are many). What is the **business** reason given to switch to JS, beyond personal preferences? How much effort would be re rewrite your homemade python test framework (I assume you have one) to JS, and will it bring any benefits?

Comment: If company makes such shift in technology, you need to consider if your expert skills in Python/Selenium will be better used (and better paid) somewhere else. Do you want to spend few years to become JS/NightWatch expert, while your Python/Selenium skill atrophy? Is company willing to pay for your training while you learn the skills, or will hire outside experts?

Answer (score 2):

The silence is deafening :-)

I have no personal experience with NightWatch, but I do have experience with the quirky nature of JavaScript, and because of that experience prefer Python, especially for big projects.

[Why you never ever reprogram working code from scratch](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html) - with history of failures cause by reprogramming from scratch.

So if your company is committed to make known mistake which killed companies before, you should be aware of the consequences for your career.

Also, one of the reason I LOVE Python that it makes efforts to be easier to read.